# mathtools and hyperref badly interacting?

Tags: equations, hyperref, mathtools

I would like to: (a) have no equation numbers for non-referenced equations; (b) have hyperlinks on equations and other constructs (lemmas/theorems/etc.); (c) use autoref so that the string for the relevant reference (equation, lemma, etc.) is automatically added. the code below doesn't work, no "Equation 1/2" appears.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % For LaTeX2e



\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\Autoref[1]{\@first@ref#1,@}
\def\@throw@dot#1.#2@{#1}% discard everything after the dot
\def\@set@refname#1{%    % set \@refname to autoefname+s using \getrefbykeydefault
    \edef\@tmp{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}%
    \xdef\@tmp{\expandafter\@throw@dot\@tmp.@}%
    \ltx@IfUndefined{\@tmp autorefnameplural}%
         {\def\@refname{\@nameuse{\@tmp autorefname}}}%
         {\def\@refname{\@nameuse{\@tmp autorefnameplural}}}%
}
\def\@first@ref#1,#2{%
  \ifx#2@\autoref{#1}\let\@nextref\@gobble% only one ref, revert to normal \autoref
  \else%
    \@set@refname{#1}%  set \@refname to autoref name
    \@refname~\ref{#1}% add autoefname and first reference
    \let\@nextref\@next@ref% push processing to \@next@ref
  \fi%
  \@nextref#2%
}
\def\@next@ref#1,#2{%
   \ifx#2@ and~\ref{#1}\let\@nextref\@gobble% at end: print and+\ref and stop
   \else, \ref{#1}% print  ,+\ref and continue
   \fi%
   \@nextref#2%
}
\makeatother

\providecommand*{\equationautorefname}{Equation}


\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
referenced \label{eq:1}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
referenced too \label{eq:2}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
unreferenced
\end{equation}

Consider \autoref{eq:1} and \autoref{eq:2}. It is referenced.

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I read that the package autonum might help with, but the following doesn't work either (all I want is hyperlinked equations that are only labeled with numbers when they are referenced to):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article} % For LaTeX2e


\usepackage{amsmath}



\usepackage{autonum}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}


\makeatletter
\newcommand\Autoref[1]{\@first@ref#1,@}
\def\@throw@dot#1.#2@{#1}% discard everything after the dot
\def\@set@refname#1{%    % set \@refname to autoefname+s using \getrefbykeydefault
    \edef\@tmp{\getrefbykeydefault{#1}{anchor}{}}%
    \xdef\@tmp{\expandafter\@throw@dot\@tmp.@}%
    \ltx@IfUndefined{\@tmp autorefnameplural}%
         {\def\@refname{\@nameuse{\@tmp autorefname}}}%
         {\def\@refname{\@nameuse{\@tmp autorefnameplural}}}%
}
\def\@first@ref#1,#2{%
  \ifx#2@\autoref{#1}\let\@nextref\@gobble% only one ref, revert to normal \autoref
  \else%
    \@set@refname{#1}%  set \@refname to autoref name
    \@refname~\ref{#1}% add autoefname and first reference
    \let\@nextref\@next@ref% push processing to \@next@ref
  \fi%
  \@nextref#2%
}
\def\@next@ref#1,#2{%
   \ifx#2@ and~\ref{#1}\let\@nextref\@gobble% at end: print and+\ref and stop
   \else, \ref{#1}% print  ,+\ref and continue
   \fi%
   \@nextref#2%
}
\makeatother

\providecommand*{\equationautorefname}{Equation}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
referenced \label{eq:a}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
referenced too \label{eq:b}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
unreferenced 
\end{equation}

Consider \autoref{eq:a} and \autoref{eq:b}. It is referenced.

\ref{eq:a}

\eqref{eq:a}

\ref{eq:b}

\eqref{eq:b}

\ref{eq:a}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Your code has a problem: `hyperref` should be loaded as the very last package, with very few exceptions – most notably `cleveref` should be loaded after hyperref.

Comment: @Bernard reordering all of these commands and adding cleveref doesn't help. I tried all permutations on mathtools/hyperref/cleveref and the mathtools command.

Comment: as the documentation of mathtools clearly says, `showonlyrefs` only monitors `\eqref`. It neither works with `\autoref`, nor `\ref` nor other reference commands.

Comment: thanks @UlrikeFischer. So what are my options as I state in the beginning for what I want to do?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I just bumped into it. Anyway, `zref-clever` has support for `mathtools`'s `showonlyrefs` option. So you can have something like:

```tex
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs,showmanualtags}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
referenced \label{eq:a}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
referenced too \label{eq:b}
\end{align}

\begin{equation}
unreferenced
\end{equation}

Consider \zcref{eq:a, eq:b}. They are referenced.

\end{document}
```

[image]