Alternative to the combo cleveref and autonum
The combo cleveref and autonum make the output clean and efficient.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
If A then
\begin{align}
B &= C , \label{thm:eq1} \\
E &= F . \label{thm:eq2}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

From \cref{thm}, we have \eqref{thm:eq2}.

\end{document}


However, cleveref is not compatible with option showonlyrefs of mathtools. Also, autonum, which relies on etextools, is not compatible with biblatex. That being said, this combo is quite buggy.
Could you suggest some alternative stable solution to automatic naming of theorems and automatic numbering of referenced equations?

zref-clever has support for mathtools' showonlyrefs. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/692055/105447. (There was some better link than that, but I'm having trouble finding it).

@gusbrs would that require replacing \label with \zlabel?

Here, a better question, using autonum: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/724552/105447

@cfr No, since the advent of the label hook from the kernel, zref-clever recommends the use of \label instead of \zlabel (and it was always required in amsmath display math environments even before that anyway). What you need is to use \zcref instead of \cref etc.

As a reader, I’d find it very ambiguous if just one equation is numbered in an align; would a cross reference be to just one of them or to both? Maybe they’re three and the numbered one is in the middle: ambiguity increases a lot.

zref-clever is certainly a better option than the following. However, the combination of autonum, cleveref and biblatex works as far as I can tell. That's not very far and you need to tweak the preamble and figure out how to modify the hints in the answer and comments you linked, but it is at least not immediately obvious this option is a non-starter.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\makeatletter
\def\blx@noerroretextools{aardvark}
\makeatother
\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}
\usepackage[noabbrev,capitalize,nameinlink]{cleveref}
\usepackage{autonum}
% \show\forlistloop
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\bibliography{biblatex-examples}
\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
  If A then
  \begin{align}
    B &= C , \label{thm:eq1} \\
    E &= F . \label{thm:eq2}
  \end{align}
\end{theorem}

From \cref{thm}, we have \eqref{thm:eq2}.
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}

This code will generate a warning from Biblatex telling you etextools is incompatible and what you need to do about it. The instructions say you need to redefine \forlistloop before biblatex is loaded. This is a bit misleading since etextools is actually loaded after biblatex.
Although Biblatex obviously could not know this, as it turns out, the warning is also unnecessary provided etextools is ONLY loaded by autonum. autonum restores the definition of \forlistloop from etoolbox, which is the one biblatex wants, after loading etextools.
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter % The missing \makeatother command is on purpose (as every other combination results in an error).
\let\autonum@etoolbox@forlistloop\forlistloop
\RequirePackage{etextools}
\let\forlistloop\autonum@etoolbox@forlistloop

Note that \makeatletter should not be used in a .sty file, though it is harmless provided \makeatother is omitted, because LaTeX ensures @ is a letter when parsing .sty files.
autonum does some other odd things. I only really looked at a few lines, but it also has
\PassOptionsToPackage{hypertexnames=false}{hyperref}

Yet the documentation says that hyperref must be loaded before autonum, so this code will do nothing unless users ignore the documentation.

Interesting, I didn't know this could be made to work, even if the path is a little tortuous. +1

@gusbrs it isn't really tortuous from the author perspective. you just have to define a single macro. the tortuous bit is figuring out that that's what you have to do ;). I wouldn't trust it to work while I turned my back, mind. but if you have an existing document and just want to fix it to compile and be done with it, I'd think it worth a shot.

Well, between, that "difficult" way to disable the biblatex error and checking the definition of \forlistloop is the correct one we got quite a ride.  ;-)  But, this is actually a cool answer. As I said, I didn't know that.

@gusbrs neither did I. but what I meant was, once somebody writes an answer telling you that's all you have to do, what you actually have to do is pretty minimal. assuming it works in a real document, which I wouldn't bet on. I'd try it, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

@gusbrs Thank you for creating zref-clever which also works nicely with \usepackage[notcite,notref]{showkeys}.

well I can only refer to my comment here https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/703076/autonum-and-restatable-incompatible#comment1749015_703076 and advise to drop autonum.

@Akira zref-clever does not redefine \label so, as long as you are using that, which is recommended anyway, I'd expect no problems with showkeys if you are using its notref option. However, \zcref is not supported by showkeys.

@gusbrs the combo of settings in my below MVE is already good for me.

@UlrikeFischer is it not clear enough I don't think this is a good solution?

A nice solution is the combo zref-clever, showkeys and mathtools (with option showonlyrefs):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,biblatex}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{S}
\usepackage[notcite,notref]{showkeys}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=blue,
  filecolor=blue,
  urlcolor=red,
  citecolor=magenta
}

\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document} 

\section{Introduction} \label{chap}

\begin{theorem} \label{thm}
If A then
\begin{align}
B &= C , \label{thm:eq1} \\
X &= Y . \label{thm:eq4}
\end{align}
\end{theorem}

From \zcref{thm} in \zcref{chap}, we have \eqref{thm:eq1}.

\end{document}



As I commented in the other link, zref-clever has full support for showonlyrefs, meaning you can use \zcref{thm:eq1} instead of \eqref{thm:eq1}, and get the type name of the equation too.

@gusbrs Could you have a look at my problem with zref-clever at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/730782/cross-reference-jump-with-zref-clever-is-incorrect?
