Cross-reference jump with "zref-clever" is incorrect
I have a tex file
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,xpatch}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {}{\usebeamerfont*{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi
  \inserttheorempunctuation}
  %\normalfont
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
  
\xpatchcmd{\@zcref}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\let\lemma\@undefined
\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Introduction
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{lemma} \label{thm1}
If A then B
\end{lemma}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
We use \zcref{thm1}.

We use \ref{thm1}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}


When I click on the cross-reference Lemma 1 in slide 3, it jumps incorrectly to slide 1 which does not contain the content of Lemma 1. Could you elaborate on this issue?

Update: the normal \ref jumps slightly below the right location:


Just for checking (not at pc). Does normal ref jump to the right location?  If not then it's probably not zref-clever that's the problem

Unrelated, but your preamble could do with a clean-up. Most of the packages aren't necessary in beamer

@daleif the normal \ref jumps slightly below the right location

I even do not get "Lemma 1" but "Lemma 0" with an up-to-date TeX Live 2024.

@cabohah I compile it on Overleaf.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have cleaned up the preamble.

You don't need the ams* packages as well as hyperref, beamer loads them automatically

@cabohah With a current latex installation, you'll need to add \let\thelemma\@undefined

This is on beamer which is cruel in its handling of hyperref anchors. But zref-clever's user manual has a workaround for it (search for beamer), you might find useful, check it out. Also, whatever you are trying to do with \xpatchcmd{\@zcref}{\begingroup}{\begingroup\bfseries}{}{} makes no sense at all (\@zcref doesn't even exist).

Note: With an up-to-date version of zref-clever 2024-11-16 0.4.9 the link is already correct without any change. So the problem is meanwhile because of the usage of an out-dated package version and I therefore suggest to close the question, though the shown code contains some additional issues.

@cabohah I wonder how long does it take Overleaf to use the updated version of your package.

It's not my package. Nevertheless TeX.SX has the close reason of using out-dated packages. If you want to know, how to update single packages when using Overleaf, ask a question (but I guess there is already one).

@Akira overleaf does not update packages and only provides a new texlive version once a year. So you should get the new zref-clever version around July or August next year.

In beamer anchors are not created by a command like \refstepcounter but by the label command and with the name of the label key. So in the following example, from \label{thm1} and \label{thm2} the anchors thm1 and thm2 are created (at different places, so the \ref jumps to different places too). Sadly beamer creates the anchor after writing the label and also doesn't correctly update \@currentHref. That makes it hard for other reference systems to target the anchor. You can correct that like this.
Unrelated but due to a change in LaTeX you will also have to undefine \thelemma when you create your theorem.
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,xpatch}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {}{\usebeamerfont*{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi
  \inserttheorempunctuation}
  %\normalfont
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}

\makeatletter  
\let\lemma\@undefined
\let\thelemma\@undefined %<--- needed

\AddToHookWithArguments{label}[helpzrefclever]{\gdef\@currentHref{#1}}
\DeclareHookRule{label}{helpzrefclever}{before}{zref-clever}
\makeatother

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Introduction
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}

\begin{lemma} \label{thm1}
If A then B

\vspace{5cm}

If C then D  \label{thm2}
\end{lemma}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
We use \zcref{thm1}.

We use \ref{thm1}, \ref{thm2}.

\end{frame}

\end{document}


That's interesting. I don't know beamer's internals well enough, does this work with overlays too? If so, I might as well replace the more complicated workaround in the manual with this.

@gusbrs I added an issue for beamer: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/917. And yes the \makeatother was wrong ...

NOTE: The solution for the main issue shown here is meanwhile outdated and you should not use the shown workaround any longer, but prefer an update of zref-clever. However it could still be useful for users of zref-clever before version 2024-11-16 v0.4.9, who are not able to update, and it also addresses additional information. So I currently don't delete it.

You can use the beamer workaround from section “14 Work-arounds” of the zref-clever documentation:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcsetup{cap=true}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{theorem begin}
{%
\begin{\inserttheoremblockenv}
  {}{\usebeamerfont*{block title}\usebeamercolor[fg]{block title}%
  \inserttheoremname
  \inserttheoremnumber
  \ifx \inserttheoremaddition \empty \else\ (\inserttheoremaddition)\fi
  \inserttheorempunctuation}
  %\normalfont
  }
  \setbeamertemplate{theorem end}{\end{\inserttheoremblockenv}}
  
% From "14 Work-around 2", "beamer" in zref-clever's documentation:
\RenewDocumentCommand{\zlabel}{ D<>{1} m }{%
  \ifx\label\ltx@gobble
  \else
    \zref@wrapper@babel{\zref@label<#1>}{#2}%
  \fi
}
\NewCommandCopy\beamer@old@zref@label\zref@label
\RenewDocumentCommand{\zref@label}{ D<>{1} m }{%
  \alt<#1>{%
    \zref@ifpropundefined{anchor}{}{\zref@setcurrent{anchor}{#2}}%
    \beamer@old@zref@label{#2}%
    \beamer@nameslide{#2}%
  }{%
    \beamer@dummynameslide%
  }%
}

\let\thelemma\@undefined% needed with up-to-date LaTeX distribution
\let\lemma\@undefined
\makeatother
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Introduction
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\begin{lemma} \label{thm1}
If A then B
\end{lemma}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
We use \zcref{thm1}.

We use \ref{thm1}.
\end{frame}

\end{document}

If you don't use \ref but only \zcref, you can replace \label by \zlabel.
BTW: If you want all zref-clever references in bold, you can add something like
\zcsetup{font=\bfseries}

to your document preamble.

+1 again. :-) I was about to comment on the xpatch thing, but I see you figured that one out too.

@gusbrs Yes. But there is still one thing, I've not figured out: The destination with same identifier warning when using \label. With \zlabel it does not occur (but then \ref does not work).

cabohah, yes that is unfortunate, but harmless, as explained in the discussion.
