How to compress references on equations?
In the tex file I used \begin{equation} and \end{equation} for all equations but some equations does not have reference.
I use the mathtools package to hide formula numbers that are not referenced in the text.
Edit.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
1+1    
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
2+2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3} % It is no ref in text
3+3    
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
4+4    
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq1}, \eqref{eq2}, \eqref{eq4}
    
\end{document}

In the output file one can see

Question. How to compress references on equations to (1)-(3)?
I am looking for analog \citen{} for equations.

For an automated option, you could use zref-clever, which has support for mathtools' showonlyrefs:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{zref-clever}
\zcLanguageSetup{english}
  {
    type=equation,
      rangesep={--},
      % with -- as rangesep, you may also want to:
      rangetopair=false,
  }

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
1+1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
2+2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3} % It is no ref in text
3+3
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
4+4
\end{equation}

\zcref{eq1, eq2, eq4}

\end{document}


You could also do it manually, using \noeqref for the "hidden" elements of the range:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, allcolors=blue]{hyperref}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
1+1
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
2+2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3} % It is no ref in text
3+3
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
4+4
\end{equation}

\eqref{eq1}\noeqref{eq2}--\eqref{eq4}

\end{document}


Use \cref from cleveref package and the autonum package.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
1+1    
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
2+2
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
3+3    
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq4}
  4+4
\end{equation}

\cref{eq1,eq2,eq3,eq4}

\end{document}



Thank you for the answer. I use the mathtools package to hide formula numbers that are not referenced in the text. Your code works without the mathtools package, but does not provide a solution when it used. How to use mathtools and cleveref packages together?
I edited my example.

Well, then I would recommend directly writing something like \eqref{eq1}--\eqref{eq3} without loading cleveref.@Nick

cleveref is not compatible with the showonlyrefs option of mathtools.

I have used \eqref{eq1}--\eqref{eq3}, but in this case the equation number with \label{eq2} is hide.

See the updated answer@Nick

@Nick - The cleveref package has always been seriously incompatible with the \mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs} tool of the mathtools package. Fortunately, an alternative to this tool is available: The autonum package. Just be sure to load autonum after cleveref.

@Nick See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/728359/105447 for both a cleveref + autonum workaround (and some discussion about it) and an alternative.
